# How to get the notifications in my External system(AdobeConnect) using salesforce change events or platform events?

Tags: apex, lightning, rest-api, platform-event, change-data-capture

I have a custom object called AdobeMeeting__c and platform event Meeting__e.
If I did the changes in AdobeMeeting__c object,I need to push the notification to my external system(adobe connect).

For that I have created a trigger on AdobeMeeting__c object and it push the changes to platform event Meeting__e.

But here my question is how can I subscribe the channel and get the notifications in my external system.

is it possible with lightning:empapi or cometD? and if both which is best ?

Can any One tell me the flow how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Connect has a rich API](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/webservices/introduction-connect-web-services.html) -- why not exploit it?

As far as I can see, it is a web services API (not REST API) so you'll need to use these Salesforce resources to help you:

- [Apex SOAP Callouts](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_soap_callouts) - an Apex solution
- [Salesforce Outbound Messaging via Workflow rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_understanding.htm) and [Outbound Message Actions Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_managing_outbound_messages.htm&type=5)

There are also middleware solutions like Mulesoft, Boomi, etc. worth considering.